# How do I program-select multiple items in a ListView in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx-8

Oracle docs say about “selectIndices”: This method allows for one or more selections to be set at the same time.
selectIndices(int index, int... indices)
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html

It does not accept an int[] array. It accepts ints separated with commas:

```
list.getSelectionModel().selectIndices(0,2);
```

But how to do this in program? 
I can manually select multiple items in the ListView OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does accept an `int[]` array, but only as second parameter. The only inconvenience is that there is a first parameter to ensure you pass at least one index.
Fortunately [`selectIndices`'s contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html#selectIndices-int-int...-) also contains a part that allows you to pass a value as first parameter that will be ignored:

> It will ignore any value that is not within the valid range (i.e. greater than or equal to zero, and less than the total number of items in the underlying data model).

So you can safely pass `-1` as first parameter and all the indices to select as second parameter.

#### Example

```
private static void select(ListView<?> listView, int divisor, int remainder) {
    MultipleSelectionModel<?> selectionModel = listView.getSelectionModel();

    // create array of indices to select        
    final int size = listView.getItems().size();
    int selectionSize = size / divisor;
    if (size % divisor > remainder) {
        selectionSize++;
    }
    int[] selectedIndices = new int[selectionSize];
    for (int i = 0, value = remainder; i < selectionSize; i++, value += divisor) {
        selectedIndices[i] = value;
    }

    // unselect currently selected items
    selectionModel.clearSelection();

    // select indices in the array
    selectionModel.selectIndices(-1, selectedIndices);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ListView<Integer> listView = new ListView<>();
    listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
        listView.getItems().add(i);
    }
    
    Button btn = new Button("Select Even");
    btn.setOnAction(evt -> select(listView, 2, 0));

    Button btn2 = new Button("Select Odd");
    btn2.setOnAction(evt -> select(listView, 2, 1));

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(10, listView, btn, btn2));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```